# How to get class name through JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How do I get the class name through JavaScript given no id with this `span`.

Like: `<span class="xyz"></span>`

I want to change the background color of this `span`.

How can I solve this? Please help me.

tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3PageTransitions/index3.html#contact

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also you have to clarify whether you want to get the class of that element, or find that element given its class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Get Element By Class in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    if (spans[i].className == 'xyz') {
        spans[i].style.backgroundColor = '#000';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have the following choices:

1. Use `document.getElementsByClassName("xyz")`.  This will return a NodeList (like an array) of objects that have that class name.  Unfortunately, this function does not exist in older versions of IE.
2. Use `document.getElementsByTagName("span")` and then loop over those objects, testing the `.className` property to see which ones have the desired class.
3. Use `document.querySelectorAll(".xyz")` to fetch the desired objects with that class name.  Unfortunately this function does not exist in older browsers.
4. Get a library that automatically handles all CSS3 selector queries in all browsers.  If you want just a selector library, then you can use Sizzle.  If you want a more comprehensive library for manipulating the DOM, then use YUI3 or jQuery (both of which have Sizzle built-in).

As of 2011, my advice is option #4.  Unless this is a very small project, your development productivity will improve immensely by using a CSS3 selector library that has already been developed for cross-browser use.  For example in Sizzle, you can get an array of objects with your class name with this line of code:

```
var list = Sizzle(".xyz");
```

In jQuery, you can create a jQuery object that contains a list of objects with that class with this line of code:

```
var list = $(".xyz");
```

And, both of these will work in all browsers since IE6 without you having to worry about any browser compatibility.

---

In more modern times (like 2021), you can use built in `document.querySelectorAll()` and see fairly rich CSS3 selector support.

Comment: Added several new options and rewrote the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `document.getElementsByClassName('xyz')`. Note: it returns <s>an array</s> a NodeList (thanks to @IAbstractDownvoteFactory) since there can be multiple elements with the same class.

```
var spans = document.getElementByClassName('xyz');
var i;
for(i=0; i<spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].style.backgroundColor = your_color;
}
```

Comment: it returns a NodeList, it's very close to an array though.

Comment: (a) Not supported in IE before 9 (b) Getting the class of an element is different than getting an element by class (guess the OP has to clarify here).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a jquery to solve the same issue.

```
 var classname = $(this).attr('class'); //here you will get current class name if its with multiple class split it and take first class.
   $("."+classname.split(" ")[0]).css("background-color", "yellow");
```