# WebDriver can't select from JQuery dropdown

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, webdriver

I have a web form having JQuery dropdowns. The particular field holds date of birth. The source for the field is:

```
<div class="tooltipGroup" style="z-index:19;">
   <div class="day">
      <div class="jqTransformSelectWrapper" style="z-index: 19;">
      <div>
         <ul style="width: 100%; display: block; visibility: visible;">
          <li class="optHeading">
          <li class="undefined">
          <li class="undefined">
          <li class="undefined">
          <li class="undefined">
          <li class="undefined">
          <li class="undefined">
             <a index="6" href="#">6</a>
      </li>

         <li class="undefined">
             <a index="31" href="#">31</a>
       </li>
```

That's the code trying to get all of the elements and put them in a HashMap:

```
public void selectDob(int dob) {

        WebElement dobFieldDropdown;

        WebElement content = driver.findElement(By.className("leftClmn"));

        driver.findElement(By.id("aWrapper_dob_day")).click();

        dobFieldDropdown = content.findElements(By.className("tooltipGroup")).get(2).findElement(By.className("day")).findElement(By.tagName("ul"));

        HashMap<String, WebElement> dropdownValues = new HashMap<String, WebElement>();

        for (WebElement el : dobFieldDropdown.findElements(By.tagName("a"))) {
            dropdownValues.put(el.getText(), el);

            System.out.println(el.getText());
        }
        dropdownValues.get(dob).click();

    }
```

The code works just fine with one exception: it can't get the values of all fields, just the first visible when the dropdown is being opened.

> 1 2 3 4 5

The question is how to get the values of the other fields?

Comment: Maybe JavascriptExecutor will help?

Comment: can you show us the webpage or any look alike page?

Comment: It is something like [link](http://tympanus.net/Development/SimpleDropDownEffects/)

Comment: If that is the case. Webdriver fetches all values present in the dropdown, but you were mentioning about only the first visible values. So i just wanted to see such a page where some options will not be visible until we scroll down more.

Comment: @HemChe Yes, in my case there is a scroll to list all of the values. When you open the dropdown only the firts 4 options are shown

Comment: Does the visible values and invisible values have different class names ?

Comment: @HemChe No, all of them are with <li class="undefined">

Comment: Kindly check the answer that i have provided and see if it is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to thank you guys for your help (especially HemChe).

It turned out that this is a bug in the latest FirefoxDriver version 2.32. The same code worked just fine with ChromeDriver and I've got all of the drropdown values. Downgrading the selenium version to 2.31 solved that problem and the code works with both drivers!

I'll register a bug on the Selenium bug tracker!

That's the final version of my code:

```
public void selectFromDropdown(String option) {

        WebElement dobFieldDropdown;

        WebElement content = driver.findElement(By.className("leftClmn"));

        driver.findElement(By.id("aWrapper_dob_day")).click();

        dobFieldDropdown = content.findElements(By.className("tooltipGroup")).get(2).findElement(By.className("day")).findElement(By.tagName("ul"));

        HashMap<String, WebElement> dropdownValues = new HashMap<String, WebElement>();

        for (WebElement el : dobFieldDropdown.findElements(By.tagName("a"))) {
            dropdownValues.put(el.getText(), el);

            System.out.println(el.getText().toString());
        }
        dropdownValues.get(option).click();

    }
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code and check if it is working.

```
    WebElement w = driver.findElement(By.id("aWrapper_dob_day"));
    w.click();
    WebElement dobFieldDropdown = driver.findElements(By.className("undefined"));

    HashMap<String, WebElement> dropdownValues = new HashMap<String, WebElement>();

    for (WebElement el : dobFieldDropdown) {
        dropdownValues.put(el.getText(), el);

        System.out.println(el.getText());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks HemChe, but unfortunately I'm still having the same problem - the method is getting only the first  five values visible after the dropdown gets expanded, the sysout for the other is empty...

Comment: Maybe JavascriptExecutor can do the trick but I haven't use it before :-(

Comment: What is dropdownValues.size() returing? i just wanted to know, if all the hidden elements count is also getting included or not.

Comment: The sysout from System.out.println(el.getText()); is 

Day
1
2
3
4
5

and 25 empty lines = total 31 days

The  System.out.println(dropdownValues.size()); is 7

Comment: If it is not confidential, share the webpage with me so that i can debug the issue.

Comment: Dear HemChe, how I can send u the url privately?

Answer (score 1):

You can't locate invisible elements with Web Driver, you need to use JavaScript in order to obtain them. So try something like

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("get them here by class name");
```

Comment: I've tried this way BUT I've got the error 

**The method executeScript(String, Object...) in the type JavascriptExecutor is not applicable for the arguments (List<WebElement>)**


`for (WebElement el : dobFieldDropdown.findElements(By.tagName("ul"))) {
            
            
            js.executeScript(dobFieldDropdown.findElements(By.tagName("a")));
            dropdownValues.put(el.getText(), el);

            System.out.println(el.getText());
        }`

Comment: No, you need to do the search for elements in JavaScript, something like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796127/how-to-get-class-name-through-javascript