# Get the class value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I may sound stupid but I am trying to get the value of a class attribute. But it is spitting undefined, while rest of the properties are working fine. I searched on stackoverflow but those are using byClassName or byTagName but I want byElementId [JSBIN Link](http://jsbin.com/kihijosime/edit?html,js,console,output)

This is the function

```
(function() {
  var fname = document.getElementById("fname");
  console.log(fname.id); //fname
  console.log(fname.name); //firstName
  console.log(fname.class); //undefined    
})();
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="fname" class="gotcha">
```

Comment: you access class via .className, alternatively you can use .getAttribute('class')

Comment: potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796127/how-to-get-class-name-through-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)** property to get class

```js
(function() {
  var fname = document.getElementById("fname");
  console.log(fname.id); //fname
  console.log(fname.name); //firstName
  console.log(fname.className); //undefined

})();
```

```html
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="fname" class="gotcha">
```

Comment: @fruitjs : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function() {
      var fname = document.getElementById("fname");
      console.log(fname.id); //fname
      console.log(fname.name); //firstName
      console.log(fname.className);
    
    })();
```

```html
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="fname" class="gotcha">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery

```
$('#fname').attr('class')
```

Using Javascript

```
document.getElementById("fname").className
```