# How to get the className of an element in JSDOM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I'm trying to get the `className` of an element using JSDOM. I am able to find the element and I'm sure it exists. I've tried looking online but can't find an example of how to find the `className` of said element using JSDOM. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: but based on what? you want to to find the classname of elemet, but on what element??
if ever you got the element and you need its classname check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796127/how-to-get-class-name-through-javascript

Comment: I am finding the element with descendants selectors, something like `div > a`, but I need to find the class name of the `a` tag. It's class changes so it has to be dynamic. I've tried using `.className` in JSDOM but it outputs an object instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

When you got your element and you wanted its classname you can use `className` from element object.

```
var element = document.getElementById("demo");
console.log(element.className)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo" class="sample_class"></p>

<script>
console.log(document.getElementById("demo").className);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem. In JSDOM you need to use `element.className.baseVal` to get classes as a string.