# How to get element by class name

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to know if there is a way to `getElementByClassName("classname").innerHTML` function or something to the equivalent of `getElementById("ClassName").innerHTML`.

Comment: This should help you. http://javascript.about.com/library/bldom08.htm
But quick tip -> Use Jquery for that. It's gonna be way easier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Get Element By Class in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript) - I assume you are dealing with JavaScript.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are missing an `s` in your function name. `getElementsByTagName` returns a collection of elements, of elements, which you need to iterate over:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].innerHTML = 'foo';
}
```

IE8 and below don't support `getElementsByClassName`, so you'll have to find a polyfill or use `querySelectorAll` (IE8).

Comment: Note that `getElementsByClassName` is not available in IE8 and below.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use JQuery, where you can use directly CSS selectors (like .yourclass) to find all elements of a given class:

```
$('.yourclass').doWhatYouWant();
```

If you prefer not to use JQuery, you can use plain Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('my-fancy-class')
```

But be careful with IE8 incompatibility issue.
As an alternative (slower but you can build more complex CSS selectors) you can use:

```
document.querySelector('.cssSelector')
```

Which will return **one element** responding to your CSS selector, or

```
document.querySelectorAll('.cssSelector')
```

Which will return multiple elements instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jquery

```
$('.className').html();
```

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Hey this answer helped me to answer the usage of class element in js. May not have been that relevant to the question above but it helped me to figure out horizontal scrolling problem i was having.

Answer (score -2):

If tou use jQuery you can get it as you would in a CSS selector so:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then...

```
$('.classname').each(function() {
    // get html
    $(this).html();
    // set html
    $(this).html('something');
});
```

Notice you have also convenient way to manage innerHTML.

Comment: This will only give you html for the first element with this class. In reality there could be many so probably you would have to use something like `each()` or similar to process them all.

Comment: Still not good even after the edit... check Blender's answer for correct way to do it.

Comment: It should work now... Effectively it doesn't add much information than Blender's answer, but thank you.

Comment: Inside of the `each` callback you should be using `$(this).html()` instead of `$('.classname').html()`. My previous comments also apply to all other answers here that are not using `each` and calling methods directly on JQuery selectors.

Comment: Correcting already written code outside of an editor is often a road fraught with danger! Thanks again ivantod.