# xml inside html

Tags: javascript, html, xml

What is the issue regarding placing xml elements inside html ? I am trying to easily retrieve javascript event info which returns some html when a div is clicked on. I want to parse that (as I cant send any data object afaik) and its very easy so I'm doing

```
<a href="#" onClick="doTap(this); return false;"><div><currency>eur</currency><price>120</price><weight>2kg</weight></div></a>
```

and in the js im doing

```
doTap=function(sent) {      

        console.log(sent.getElementsByTagName('price')[0].innerHTML);
```

Comment: The issue is that XML is not valid HTML (with respect to the elements). It seems you are fine with using `span` elements and giving them a class.

Comment: @FelixKling — you should expand that into an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that XML is not valid HTML (with respect to the elements). The browser does not know how to render a `currency` element, and afaik there is no standard way to deal with unknown elements. Some browsers might ignore them completely.

You should be fine with using `span` elements and giving them a class:

```
<div>
    <span class="currency">eur</span>
    <span class="price">120</span><
    <span class="weight">2kg</span>
</div>
```

<sup>`a` elements are not supposed to contain block elements btw.</sup>

Then [get the element in question by its class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript).

---

If you don't want to display the information (currency, price, etc) but only need to store it somewhere, you can use HTML5's [`data-*` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/):

```
<a data-currency-"eur" ... ></a>
```

and access them with [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute).

Comment: In particular, really, really weird things can happen in IE8. For example, unknown elements with "block" display (sometimes? always?) don't implicitly close `<p>` tags, with very strange results.

Answer (score 0):

The main practical problem is that IE 8 and older do not deal at all with tags they don’t know when processing HTML documents. To deal with this, you can add code like `document.createElement('currency')`.

There are other issues, too, such as the risk that some future browsers will start recognizing the markup you have invented – and this may cause unpredictable rendering features and functionality. Some more notes: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/pragmatic-html.html8#custom

The safer approach is to use `span` elements with `class`. You can also use `a` elements, since without `href`, they are still valid but do not create links, making the element effectively just a text-level container. By HTML syntax rules, though, you must not nest `a` elements (but browsers don’t care, in things like this).

So the safest approach uses e.g. `<span class=currency>EUR</span>` etc. instead.

Comment: I'm happy to use span but I'm just not sure how to get the data easily thats why I tried with xml. I'm not trying to get an element of the DOM in this case its an event cause by onClick.

Comment: It becomes just a little more complicated when using `span` with class, e.g. get all `span` elements and then pick up those with the right class. And you need the DOM anyway – even `getElementsByTagName` relies on the DOM.

Comment: This is my point I don't want to use the DOM thats why I used xml ! I'm working on an event sent via onClick which afaik a small piece of html in my case so a segment of the original DOM. Or is this not how it works. I know that this MUST have been a problem for so many people before. I am using html5 so that might be meaning the a tag solution given above. But will that work on NON DOM html.

Comment: I have no idea of what you mean by non-DOM html and why don’t want to use the DOM. In any case, using XML markup inside HTML will not avoid the DOM

Comment: when you click an html anchor with an onClick event what gets passed ? It isnt the DOM it is a selection of html representing the item clicked. AFAIK - perhaps I am wrong. But DOM functions just don't work. Im trying to get information into the event about which button was pressed.