# How to create effective "select all" checkbox in JSF

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I want to implement select all checkbox into JSF `h:datatable`. This is the code if the `h:datatable`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <ui:insert name="header">           
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>         
        </ui:insert>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h1><img src="resources/css/images/icon.png" alt="DX-57" /> History Center</h1>
        <!-- layer for black background of the buttons -->
        <div id="toolbar" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1180px; height:30px; position:relative;  background-color:black">
            <!-- Include page Navigation -->
            <ui:insert name="Navigation">           
                <ui:include src="Navigation.xhtml"/>         
            </ui:insert>

        </div>  

        <div id="logodiv" style="position:relative; top:35px; left:0px;"> 
            <h:graphicImage alt="Dashboard"  style="position:relative; top:-20px; left:9px;"  value="resources/images/logo_sessions.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:700px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:105px">

            <div id="mainpage" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:500px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:80px">

                <div id="settingsHashMap" style="width:750px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px">

                    <h:form id="form">

                        <ui:debug />

                        <!-- The sortable data table -->
                        <h:dataTable id="dataTable" value="#{SessionsController.dataList}" binding="#{table}" var="item">
                            <!-- Check box -->
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Select" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox onclick="highlight(this)" value="#{SessionsController.selectedIds[item.aSessionID]}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="№" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="№" value="№" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{table.rowIndex + SessionsController.firstRow + 1}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Account Session ID" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Account Session ID" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.aSessionID}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="User ID" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="User ID" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.userID}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity Start Time" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity Start Time" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activityStart}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity End Time" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity End Time" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activityEnd}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activity}" />
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>

                        <!-- The paging buttons -->
                        <h:commandButton value="first" action="#{SessionsController.pageFirst}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow == 0}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>


                        <h:commandButton value="prev" action="#{SessionsController.pagePrevious}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow == 0}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>

                        <h:commandButton value="next" action="#{SessionsController.pageNext}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow + SessionsController.rowsPerPage >= SessionsController.totalRows}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>    

                        <h:commandButton value="last" action="#{SessionsController.pageLast}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow + SessionsController.rowsPerPage >= SessionsController.totalRows}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>

                        <h:outputText value="Page #{SessionsController.currentPage} / #{SessionsController.totalPages}" />
                        <br />

                        <!-- The paging links -->
                        <ui:repeat value="#{SessionsController.pages}" var="page">
                            <h:commandLink value="#{page}" actionListener="#{SessionsController.page}"
                                           rendered="#{page != SessionsController.currentPage}" >
                                <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>   
                            </h:commandLink>
                            <h:outputText value="#{page}" escape="false"
                                          rendered="#{page == SessionsController.currentPage}" />
                        </ui:repeat>
                        <br />

                        <!-- Set rows per page -->
                        <h:outputLabel for="rowsPerPage" value="Rows per page" />
                        <h:inputText id="rowsPerPage" value="#{SessionsController.rowsPerPage}" size="3" maxlength="3" />
                        <h:commandButton value="Set" action="#{SessionsController.pageFirst}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>
                        <h:message for="rowsPerPage" errorStyle="color: red;" />

                        <h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{SessionsController.deleteSelectedIDs}" >

                        </h:commandButton>

                    </h:form>                  

                </div>   

                <div id="settingsdivb" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:20px; left:800px">

                </div>   
            </div>  
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

This is the managed bean:

```
package com.DX_57.HM_57;
/*
 * include default packages for Beans
 */

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
// or import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
/*
 * include SQL Packages
 */
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.*;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.component.UICommand;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
// or import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean; 
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import org.glassfish.osgicdi.OSGiService;

@Named("SessionsController")
@ViewScoped
public class Sessions implements Serializable {

    /*
     * Call the Oracle JDBC Connection driver
     */
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/Oracle")
    private DataSource ds;
    // Data.
    private List<ActiveSessionObj> dataList;
    // Rows
    private int totalRows;
    // Paging.
    private int firstRow;
    private int rowsPerPage;
    private int totalPages;
    private int pageRange;
    private Integer[] pages;
    private int currentPage;
    // Sorting.
    private String sortField;
    private boolean sortAscending;

    /*
     * Constructor
     */
    public Sessions() {
        /*
         * Set default properties
         */
        rowsPerPage = 10; // Default rows per page (max amount of rows to be displayed at once).
        pageRange = 10; // Default page range (max amount of page links to be displayed at once).
        sortField = "ASESSIONID"; // Default sort field.
        sortAscending = true; // Default sort direction.
    }

    public class ActiveSessionObj {

        /*
         * Oracle table structure CREATE TABLE ACTIVESESSIONSLOG( ASESSIONID
         * VARCHAR2(30 ) NOT NULL, USERID VARCHAR2(30 ), ACTIVITYSTART
         * TIMESTAMP(6), ACTIVITYEND TIMESTAMP(6), ACTIVITY CLOB )
         */
        private String aSessionID;
        private String userID;
        private Date activityStart;
        private Date activityEnd;
        private String activity;
        //private boolean selected;

        public ActiveSessionObj(String aSessionID, String userID, Date activityStart, Date activityEnd, String activity) {
            this.aSessionID = aSessionID;
            this.userID = userID;
            this.activityStart = activityStart;
            this.activityEnd = activityEnd;
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public int getFirstRow() {
            return firstRow;
        }

        public String getaSessionID() {
            return aSessionID;
        }

        public void setaSessionID(String aSessionID) {
            this.aSessionID = aSessionID;
        }

        public String getactivity() {
            return activity;
        }

        public void setactivity(String activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public Date getactivityEnd() {
            return activityEnd;
        }

        public void setactivityEnd(Date activityEnd) {
            this.activityEnd = activityEnd;
        }

        public Date getactivityStart() {
            return activityStart;
        }

        public void setactivityStart(Date activityStart) {
            this.activityStart = activityStart;
        }

        public String getuserID() {
            return userID;
        }

        public void setuserID(String userID) {
            this.userID = userID;
        }

        private ActiveSessionObj() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        }
    }

    // Paging actions -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void pageFirst() {
        page(0);
    }

    public void pageNext() {
        page(firstRow + rowsPerPage);
    }

    public void pagePrevious() {
        page(firstRow - rowsPerPage);
    }

    public void pageLast() {
        page(totalRows - ((totalRows % rowsPerPage != 0) ? totalRows % rowsPerPage : rowsPerPage));
    }

    public void page(ActionEvent event) {
        page(((Integer) ((UICommand) event.getComponent()).getValue() - 1) * rowsPerPage);
    }

    private void page(int firstRow) {
        this.firstRow = firstRow;
        loadDataList(); // Load requested page.
    }

    // Sorting actions ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void sort(ActionEvent event) {
        String sortFieldAttribute = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("sortField");

        // If the same field is sorted, then reverse order, else sort the new field ascending.
        if (sortField.equals(sortFieldAttribute)) {
            sortAscending = !sortAscending;
        } else {
            sortField = sortFieldAttribute;
            sortAscending = true;
        }

        pageFirst(); // Go to first page and load requested page.
    }

    // Loaders ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private void loadDataList() {

        // Load list and totalCount.
        try {
            dataList = list(firstRow, rowsPerPage, sortField, sortAscending);
            totalRows = countDBRowNum(); //count the tablerows
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        // Set currentPage, totalPages and pages.
        currentPage = (totalRows / rowsPerPage) - ((totalRows - firstRow) / rowsPerPage) + 1;
        totalPages = (totalRows / rowsPerPage) + ((totalRows % rowsPerPage != 0) ? 1 : 0);
        int pagesLength = Math.min(pageRange, totalPages);
        pages = new Integer[pagesLength];

        // firstPage must be greater than 0 and lesser than totalPages-pageLength.
        int firstPage = Math.min(Math.max(0, currentPage - (pageRange / 2)), totalPages - pagesLength);

        // Create pages (page numbers for page links).
        for (int i = 0; i < pagesLength; i++) {
            pages[i] = ++firstPage;
        }
    }

    // Getters ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public List<ActiveSessionObj> getdataList() {
        if (dataList == null) {
            loadDataList(); // Preload page for the 1st view.
        }
        return dataList;
    }

    public int getTotalRows() {
        return totalRows;
    }

    public int getFirstRow() {
        return firstRow;
    }

    public int getRowsPerPage() {
        return rowsPerPage;
    }

    public Integer[] getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

    public int getCurrentPage() {
        return currentPage;
    }

    public int getTotalPages() {
        return totalPages;
    }

    // Setters ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void setRowsPerPage(int rowsPerPage) {
        this.rowsPerPage = rowsPerPage;
    }

    // Actions ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Returns list of ActiveSessionObj items starting at the given first index
     * with the given row count, sorted by the given sort field and sort order.
     *
     * @param firstRow First index of rows to be returned.
     * @param rowCount Amount of rows to be returned.
     * @param sortField Field to sort the data on.
     * @param sortAscending Whether to sort data ascending or not.
     * @return list of ActiveSessionObj items starting at the given first index
     * with the given row count, sorted by the given sort field and sort order.
     * @throws DAOException If something fails at DAO level.
     */
    public List<ActiveSessionObj> list(int firstRow, int rowCount, String sortField, boolean sortAscending) throws SQLException {

        String SqlStatementSmall = null;
        String SQLStatementLarge = null;

        if (ds == null) {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        if (conn == null) {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        int countrow = firstRow + rowCount;
        String sortDirection = sortAscending ? "ASC" : "DESC";

        /*
         * For small tables
         */
        SqlStatementSmall = "SELECT c.*"
                + " FROM (SELECT b.*, rownum rn"
                + " FROM (SELECT a.*"
                + " FROM activeSessionsLog a"
                + " ORDER BY %s %s) b"
                + " WHERE rownum <= ?) c"
                + " WHERE rn > ?";

        /*
         * For huge datatables optimized for perfomance
         */
        SQLStatementLarge = "select * from"
                + " (select asl.*, row_number() over (order by userid asc) r "
                + " from activesessionslog asl)"
                + " where r > 980750 and r <= 980800;";


        String sql = String.format(SqlStatementSmall, sortField, sortDirection);

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        List<ActiveSessionObj> dataList = new ArrayList<ActiveSessionObj>();

        try {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            boolean committed = false;

            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, countrow);
            ps.setInt(2, firstRow);


            resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
            /*
             * take the result from the SQL query and insert it into Array List
             * collection
             */
            dataList = ActiveSessionsArrayList(resultSet);

            conn.commit();
            committed = true;



        } finally {
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        }

        return dataList;
    }

    /**
     * Returns total amount of rows in table.
     *
     * @return Total amount of rows in table.
     * @throws DAOException If something fails at DAO level.
     */
    public int countDBRowNum() throws Exception {

        String SqlStatement = null;

        if (ds == null) {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        if (conn == null) {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        SqlStatement = "SELECT count(*) FROM ACTIVESESSIONSLOG";

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        int count = 0;

        try {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            boolean committed = false;
            try {
                SqlStatement = "SELECT count(*) FROM ACTIVESESSIONSLOG";

                ps = conn.prepareStatement(SqlStatement);
                resultSet = ps.executeQuery();

                if (resultSet.next()) {
                    count = resultSet.getInt(1);
                }

                conn.commit();
                committed = true;
            } finally {
                if (!committed) {
                    conn.rollback();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        }

        return count;
    }

    /**
     * Map the current row of the given ResultSet to ActiveSessionObj.
     *
     * @param resultSet The ResultSet of which the current row is to be mapped
     * to ActiveSessionObj.
     * @return The mapped ActiveSessionObj from the current row of the given
     * ResultSet.
     * @throws SQLException If something fails at database level.
     */
    private ArrayList<ActiveSessionObj> ActiveSessionsArrayList(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        ArrayList<ActiveSessionObj> list = new ArrayList<>();


        try {
            while (rs.next()) {
                list.add(new ActiveSessionObj(
                        rs.getString("ASESSIONID"),
                        rs.getString("USERID"),
                        timestampToDate(rs.getTimestamp("ACTIVITYSTART")),
                        timestampToDate(rs.getTimestamp("ACTIVITYEND")),
                        rs.getString("ACTIVITY")));
            }
        } catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;   
    }

    //get the selected rows
    private HashMap<String, Boolean> selectedIds = new HashMap<>();

    // get the list from the JSF page
    public Map<String, Boolean> getSelectedIds() {
        return selectedIds;
    }

    //delete all selected checkboxes
    public void deleteSelectedIDs() throws SQLException {
        boolean success = false;

        if (ds == null) {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        if (conn == null) {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            boolean committed = false;
            try {

                String sqlDeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM ACTIVESESSIONSLOG WHERE ASESSIONID = ?";


                Set<String> keySet = selectedIds.keySet();
                String[] keys = new String[]{};
                keys = selectedIds.keySet().toArray(keys);
                ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlDeleteQuery);

                for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                    ps.setString(1, keys[i]);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    ps.clearParameters();
                    selectedIds.put(keys[i], false); //get(keys[i]) = false;
                }

                conn.commit();
                committed = true;

                //selectedIds.clear();
            } finally {
                if (!committed) {
                    conn.rollback();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        }

        /*
         * // Get selected items. boolean success = false; try { String
         * sqlDeleteQuery = "";
         *
         * Set<String> keySet = selectedIds.keySet(); Iterator keyIterator =
         * keySet.iterator(); while(keyIterator.hasNext()) { keyIterator.next();
         * }
         *
         * }
         * catch(Exception x) { success = false; } // Do your thing with the
         * MyData items in List selectedDataList.
         */
        //return success; // Navigation case.
    }


    private static Date timestampToDate(java.sql.Timestamp ts) {
        Date d = null;
        try {
            d = new Date(ts.getTime());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return d;
    }
}
```

My question is how I can implement elective `select all` button. One way to create java method which gets all keys of the database table and create hashmap which stores all keys. Something like this:

```
private HashMap<String, Boolean> selectedIds = new HashMap<>();
```

This code works very well when I tried to implement select row check boxes. The problem is what happens when I have one million rows or more into the into the database table? In this case all keys will be inserted into one very big hashmap and maybe I will get error because the memory consumption will be too big. Is there more optimized solution?

Best wishes
Peter

**UPDATE**

I have implemented simple check box for selecting a rows and passing them to delete java method which is deleting the rows into the database table using key. But how I can implement `select all` into JavaScript client side and call java method which deletes all records from the database table?

Comment: Is there a reason why you'd need to have the capabilities for a million rows in the table?  I have a feeling the browser would choke up pretty good just displaying the information, let alone sending back a response to the servlet.

Comment: Look at Google. Does it give the zillion of results back in a single response? No, it only returns a subset of results based on filtering (the search field) and pagination (the paging buttons). This way you ultimately end up with only a limited subset of records in memory. Component libraries like PrimeFaces offer complete ready-to-use solutions for this so that you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @dardo maybe I won't ever need to have one million rows but I want to design the JSF table to handle it.

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this

```
<h:column id="selection_column">
    <f:facet name="header">
         <h:selectBooleanCheckbox class="checkall"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{SessionsController.selectedIds[item.aSessionID]}" />
</h:column>
```

in your js put this code

```
    $(window).load(function () {
        $(document).delegate(".checkall", "click", function(event) {
              $(this).closest("table").find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
        });
    });
```

b.t.w instead of storing in map you can add attribute to your iterated `item` like this: instead of `value="#{SessionsController.selectedIds[item.aSessionID]}"` something like this `value="#{item.selected}"`

and later on you can iterate over them in the server side and add to list that will be sent to you r delete method...

Comment: I tested your example and it works but the problem is that only the rows into the first page are selected. The rows on second and so on are not selected. How I can fix this?

Comment: It supposed to select only the visible rows, what you can do is to make sure that when next page is clicked and all the rows in the current page are selected is simply to add to `selectedIds` all the ids that are gonna be visible in the next page to be displayed (no client side solution in this case), another option is : when next page clicked and all rows are displayed in current page is to add all ids to `selectedIds`...

Answer (score 4):

The selection is a client-side operation. So you can achieve that using JavaScript. An idea, is to add a specific CSS class to all the checkboxes that you want to select (it will then be easier to select them all):

```
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Select" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox styleClass="selectable-checkbox" onclick="highlight(this)" value="#{SessionsController.selectedIds[item.aSessionID]}" />
</h:column>
```

Then, you can simply use the following jQuery code to check all the elements with this specific CSS class: `jQuery(".selectable-checkbox").attr("checked", true);`.

If you are not using jQuery, you can do the same thing, tuning a little bit the code shown here: [How to Get Element By Class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript)

---

*Regarding your Edit:*

You want to have a button `Select all` that **deletes** all the items in your table?

If you need to achieve that, rename this button to `Delete all items` that will simply call a Java method (i.e. a classic `<h:commandButton>` or `<h:commandLink>`), without having to select checkboxes. What would be the interest of selecting the items, as you will delete them just after that?

Comment: Post updated. The solution selecting all rows using client side JavaScript is good. But when I implement this how I can tell to java method bean to delete all rows into the database table?

Comment: @PeterPenzov updated my answer too. What is the interest of the selection then, if you delete the items?

Comment: I want to implement it this way: I want to have one main check box which when I click it everything is selected or when everything is selected every which is deselected. The big question is when I press the main checkbox I select all rows, then I press delete button to delete all rows into the database table using the key. How I can simplify this? The only way that I can think of is using hashmap to store the keys. Is your way how JavaScript can call java method which deletes every row only when everything is selected?

Comment: Something like this example: http://debugmode.net/2010/11/01/checkboxes-in-html-table-with-jquery-checked-all-unchecked-enable-disable-operation/

Comment: `.attr` is the old way of maintaining properties of element. Use `.prop` instead. Also correctly with `.prop("checked", true)`, I'm not quite sure if it will change the UI state of a button - it won't appear as checked as it would in plain html.

Answer (score 0):

For JSF 2 ,for selected all rows in datatable in selectionMode multiple with paginator=true: 
In Page

```html
<p:dataTable widgetVar="tableArea" yourtags...>
   <p:ajax  event="toggleSelect" oncomplete="teste()" /> /// toggleSelect is dispared on click to checkbox header
<p:column id="columnId" selectionMode="multiple"/>
```

In js:

```js
function teste(){      
 var checked = $(document).find(":checkbox")["0"].checked; ///Find checkbox header and verify if checkbox is checked
 if(checked == true){
  PF('tableArea').selectAllRows(); // if true, selectAllRows from datatable
 } else {
  PF('tableArea').unselectAllRows(); //
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code to selectAll checkbox :

$(window).load(function () {

```
    $(document).delegate(".checkall", "click", function(event) {
          $(this).closest("table").find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

it is working fine when I select/deselect checkbox in header then all the checkbox under that column are selected/deselected. 
But if again Iam selecting the same, then other checkboxes are not selected. .