# Javascript - get span by the class?

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Get Element By Class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript)

I need to get the text from inside of a span. The span has no ID. It only has a class. There would only be one span with this class. Does anyone know how I can get this span element in javascript? Thanks!

```
<span class="galleria-current">1</span>
```

This is slightly different than [How to Get Element By Class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript) which is asking the more generic "get an element with a class", in case there's an easier way for spans, plus that question is about replacing text, whereas I want to *get* the innerHTML in this case.

Comment: Check out jQuery at http://jquery.com  -- with it, it's just as simple as `$('span.galleria-current')`

Comment: @Niko For one line? Hardly necessary.

Comment: @Niko, This question is not tagged jQuery, the OP is asking for a javascript solution.

Comment: @Jivings Hardly necessary for this task, yes - but probably helpful in the future.

Comment: @Gabe And jQuery is what? Right, JavaScript. Didn't say: Please don't tell me anything about such a beautiful library as jQuery.

Comment: @Niko, there are tags for a reason. I never said jQuery wasn't javascript. I will tell you what is correct, and it's simply the OP asked for a pure javascript solution. You're also making an assumption the the OP can even make use of jQuery in their solution, which is wrong.

Comment: @Gabe Since the tag says "javascript", OP might probably be interested in something like jQuery - that's the only assumption I've made. And that's why I didn't post this as an answer, it's just a note saying "maybe you'd like to check this out". No idea what's the problem with that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can use `document.getElementsByClassName()`.

This will return an Array of all the elements with that classname. So the first one could be accessed like this:

`var span = document.getElementsByClassName("galleria-current")[0]`

Comment: The only problem with this (and I was going to suggest the same thing) is that it's supported by every major browser on earth (good) except IE8 and down (bad).  See [whencaniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname).  +1 anyhow.

Comment: This is not a cross browser solution.

Comment: Except that IE8 doesn't support getElementsByClassName.

Comment: Comments are correct. This solution is not valid for older browser implementations.

Comment: This will work in Chrome/Firefox but IE does not support getElementsByClassName.

Comment: IE 9 *does* support this function.

Answer (score 4):

```
function getFirstSpanWithClass(cssClass) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if((' ' + elements[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cssClass + ' ') > -1) {
            return elements[i];
        }
    }
}

var span = getFirstSpanWithClass('galleria-current'); // should return your span element.
if (span){
    // in case there is a span on the page, write its innerHTML to console
    console.log(span.innerHTML);
}
```

And an example that will give you all of them:

```
function getSpansWithClass(cssClass) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    var out = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if((' ' + elements[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cssClass + ' ') > -1) {
            out.push(elements[i]);
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: I like this one since you can't accidentally get some "non span" that happens to have the class you're looking for...