# Javascript via element, replace single part of a table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, greasemonkey, userscripts

Long story short I'm making a greasemonkey script. The pages I work on have this specific table with various values depending on the page.

```
<table class="billing dead">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Index:</th>
            <td>Long alpha numeric value here</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Status:</th>
            <td class="status">This text is red to denote urgency.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table><!-- end billing dead -->
```

What I need to do is change the text "Index:" to something else, whether it be a button or a link depending on the situation. I'm just having a hard time actually locating the item via Javascript.

Looking around I found this: [How to Get Element By Class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript) which provided me with this code:

```
function replaceContentInContainer(matchClass,content)
{
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i;
    for (i in elems)
    {
        if((" " + elems[i].className + " ").indexOf(" " + matchClass + " ") > -1)
        {
            elems[i].innerHTML = content;
        }
    }
}
```

That replaces the whole table, however it's the closest question/answer to my situation; it's just not quite right. Once I've found the table with that method linked above, is there a way to access the elements of that specific table? I've tried arbitrarily changing

```
elems[i].innerHTML = content;
```

into

```
elems[i][0].innerHTML = content;
```

which quickly taught me that `elems[i]` isn't a node of nodes. Is there an easy way to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: Can we add a class to the `th` element containing "Index", and use that class instead of the class of the table?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using jQuery?

Comment: @JimmyX: unfortunately no. It's not a website I've generated, it's a userscript script to deal with a website I work with regularly.

Comment: @RalphLavelle: I = Noob. That's why. Can jQuery be used in chrome/firefox cross platform and as a userscript? If so, what is the best solution to this problem?

Comment: jQuery works across all browsers, generally speaking. Not sure what a userscript is. But as a general rule, if it's "find stuff, do stuff", then jQuery is what you want to use.

Comment: If you can be absolutely sure that the `th` in question will always be the first `th` in the table, look at @am not i am's answer. We don't embed the entire jQuery library where a simple line of javascript can do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there more than one "billing" table?  Is there only one "Index" per and is it always the first row?

The following, **complete script** shows how to change the HTML about any/all "Index" rows, including activating the resulting buttons.  It uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), which will save you much time and effort.

[**See the base code in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/qa2Gy/)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Buttonize the Index cells
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

//--- Find all the "Index" headers.
var indexHdrs   = $("table.billing.dead th:contains(Index)");

//--- Wrap them all in a button, for example.
indexHdrs.each ( function () {
    $(this).wrapInner ('<button class="myButton" />');
} );

/*--- Activate the buttons.  In this case they just display matching
    cell contents.
*/
$("table.billing.dead th button.myButton").click ( function () {
    var jThis           = $(this);  //-- The button that was clicked.
    var matchingCell    = jThis.parent ().next ();
    alert (matchingCell.text () );
} );
```

Note: To use this script on Chrome, install [the Tampermonkey extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) -- which you will want to do anyway, both for the extra features, and to surmount Chrome's pending restrictions on userscript installation.

Comment: Thank you very much. This actually answered my question and also solved the next step I was looking for; turning it into a button. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelector('.billing.dead > tbody > tr > th')
        .firstChild
        .data = "new value";
```

Answer (score 0):

It works well.  This is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/534f7/).

`replaceContentInContainer('status', 'hello');`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm trying to change "<th>Index:</th>" which doesn't have a class to directly link to it. Thanks though! =) EDIT: Also that website is something I'm going to use in the future, double thanks!