# javascript, how to take value from an input by class?

Tags: javascript

I use this code to get value from an input box:

```
var suggest_type = document.getElementById('ac-type').value;
```

Now I need to apply my js code on several other pages. I heard that it's not nice to repeat an ID on one website. So, I'm thinking to change to use class like this:

```
var suggest_type = document.getElementByClass('ac-type').value;
```

This doesn't get the value. How can I use class to get value?

Comment: duplicate of this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript

Comment: `getElementByClass` does not exist.

Comment: `getElementByClass` doesn't exist and the idea is semantically wrong, as there can be more elements with the same class.

Comment: Just to reiterate my answer which has received unecessary downvotes (unexplained I might add).  ID's do not need to be unique across an antire website, only within a single page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stick with using ID's - they only have to be unique within a page.

If you *must* use classes, you need to use `getElementsByClassName()`:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('ac-type');
var value = elems[0].value;
```

However this function is not well supported on older browsers, which is another good reason to stick with IDs.

Comment: I am confused as to how this is different to my answer which has receieved 2 downvotes? :/

Comment: It's not that different, except I showed how you _could_ do it with classes if you really had to.  I did upvote you, BTW.

Comment: While I agree, my point is completely valid and makes the need for selecting by class unecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I didn't know same ID on different pages of one website is valid. I will use ID.

Answer (score 1):

Its absolutely fine to repeat ids across a website just not on a single html document.

ID's should be unique within one html page.

Comment: care to elaborate with the downvotes? Or have you not bothered to read my answer properly?

Comment: I upvoted yours, but received three downvotes on mine, probably for not using the non-existent getElementByClass function ???

Comment: Maybe down vote makes some peeps feeling good of having a little power over others.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually :

```
var suggest_type = document.getElementsByClassName('ac-type')[0].value;
```

But I agree with Jon Taylor, ID's can be the same within a website, as long they are not duplicated on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('ac-type'); // this is an array containing all matched elements
```

Comment: note that instead of `getElementByClass`, I've used `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: Not only is that `getElementsByClassName`, note the *Name*, but it also doesn't work in older IEs.

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery just by using -

```
$('.ac-type').val();
```

you will get value.

Comment: Why jQuery and not Prototype.js or Mootools or Dojo or YUI or ... ? (this is a rhetorical question... if the question is not about a certain library, don't suggest to use one, unless it is really really necessary or you provide an alternative, library-free solution as well).