# Get element by class in javascript and count the number of elements in them

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Get Element By Class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript)

I have a div tag with a class name on it. I want to get that div tag using the class name and count the number of elements in them. I am not in a position to filter using ID. How do i achieve this?

Comment: A very cursory search would bring up lots of stuff on this. What have you tried?

Comment: the duplicate marker is wrong btw. the asker didnt want to "select" the elements but he wanted to count them.

Answer (score 6):

Had you googled it.

```
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("classname")

arr.length
```

Comment: you should know that not all browsers have `getElementsByClassName()`, check `<IE9`!