# How to get child element by class name?

Tags: javascript, yui

I'm trying to get the child span that has a class = 4. Here is an example element:

```
<div id="test">
 <span class="one"></span>
 <span class="two"></span>
 <span class="three"></span>
 <span class="four"></span>
</div>
```

The tools I have available are JS and YUI2. I can do something like this:

```
doc = document.getElementById('test');
notes = doc.getElementsByClassName('four');

//or

doc = YAHOO.util.Dom.get('#test');
notes = doc.getElementsByClassName('four');
```

These do not work in IE. I get an error that the object (doc) doesn't support this method or property (getElementsByClassName). I've tried a few examples of cross browser implementations of getElementsByClassName but I could not get them to work and still got that error.

I think what I need is a cross browser getElementsByClassName or I need to use doc.getElementsByTagName('span') and loop through until I find class 4. I'm not sure how to do that though.

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript

Comment: Funny enough, the more powerful `querySelectorAll` is supported by IE 8+ whereas `getElementsByClassName` is only supported by IE 9+. If you can drop IE 7, you are safe to use `querySelectorAll('.4')`. By the way, `4` is an invalid class name.

Comment: @paritybit that question doesn't work because it still utilizes getElementsByClassName and older version of IE don't seem to support that. edit: I'm sorry it uses tag name. This may work.

Comment: @Prinzhorn I do not have the YUI2 selector utility available in this product for some reason.

Comment: @spyderman4g63 I did not talk about anything YUI2 specific. `document.querySelectorAll` is DOM and has nothing to do with YUI

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Use `doc.childNodes` to iterate through each `span`, and then filter the one whose `className` equals `4`:

```
var doc = document.getElementById("test");
var notes = null;
for (var i = 0; i < doc.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (doc.childNodes[i].className == "4") {
      notes = doc.childNodes[i];
      break;
    }        
}
```

​

Comment: The problem is that getElementsByClassName doesn't work in IE8.

Comment: This code doesn't work if element has more than one class. For example: if you're looking for elements with "one" class, and your elements have "one two three" class, this function will not find them.

Comment: @FranVerona Just out of curiosity, wouldn't a simple "indexOf('className') > -1" solve the multiple class issue?

Comment: @JamesPoulose, it *wouldn't*. Consider having an element set to two classes: small and bigger. thatElement.className would return a String that equals "small bigger". If you're looking for a class called big saying myElement.className.indexOf("big") will produce something unequal to negative 1 despite that not actually being a part of the class. If you have 100% control of your class names, such a fix would work, it's just not guaranteed to, especially when your'e writing code that's going to interact code you don't have total control over.

Comment: You should use a regex match on the `className` like so: `if(doc.childNode[i].className.match("\s*" + search_class + "\s*")` where the variable `search_class` is the class name that you are looking for.

Comment: The real problem is that Typescript generates their definitions from IE so this solution doesn't work in typescript

Comment: @WebWanderer That also fails in the same scenario described by Evin. You're thinking of either `\s+` -- which fails if it's the first, last, or only class -- or `\b`, which _would_ work.

Answer (score 353):

Use querySelector and querySelectorAll

```
var testContainer = document.querySelector('#test');
var fourChildNode = testContainer.querySelector('.four');
```

IE9 and upper

Comment: This checks for all descendants, not just children.

Comment: Check compatibility at [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/queryselector)

Comment: @SUM1 [If you don't care about IE](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_scope), you can use the CSS pseudo element [`:scope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope) to check for direct descendants like this: `testContainer.querySelector(':scope > .four')`

Comment: in order to get all of the children we need to use ```var fourChildNode = testContainer.querySelectorAll('.four');```

Answer (score 51):

The accepted answer only checks immediate children.  Often times we're looking for any descendants with that class name.

Also, sometimes we want any child that *contains* a className.

For example: `<div class="img square"></div>` should match a search on className "img", even though it's *exact* className is not "img".

Here's a solution for both of these issues:

**Find the first instance of a descendant element with the class `className`**

```
   function findFirstChildByClass(element, className) {
        var foundElement = null, found;
        function recurse(element, className, found) {
            for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length && !found; i++) {
                var el = element.childNodes[i];
                var classes = el.className != undefined? el.className.split(" ") : [];
                for (var j = 0, jl = classes.length; j < jl; j++) {
                    if (classes[j] == className) {
                        found = true;
                        foundElement = element.childNodes[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(found)
                    break;
                recurse(element.childNodes[i], className, found);
            }
        }
        recurse(element, className, false);
        return foundElement;
    }
```

Comment: Nope. I *don't* want all descendants, just the child like the question asked.

Comment: For the record, I've had both use cases, descendants slightly more often, but I came here for the child use case.

Answer (score 37):

Use element.querySelector().
Lets assume:
'myElement' is the parent element you already have.
'sonClassName' is the class of the child you are looking for.

```
let child = myElement.querySelector('.sonClassName');
```

For more info, visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector

Comment: For some reason I had to use `let child = myElement.querySelector('sonClassName');` in my case

Comment: But you have to add the dot next to the class name querySelector('.sonClassName'), otherwise it will handle it as sonClassName is a tag name not a class name

Answer (score 23):

Modern solution

```
const context = document.getElementById('context');
const selected = context.querySelectorAll(':scope > div');
```

[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 15):

You could try:

```
notes = doc.querySelectorAll('.4');
```

or

```
notes = doc.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) { 
    if (notes[i].getAttribute('class') == '4') {
    }
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if browsers finally had this functionality without requiring something like jQuery, glad to see it. If anyone is curious, looks like it's supported in most modern browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 8):

To me it seems like you want the fourth span. If so, you can just do this:

```
document.getElementById("test").childNodes[3]
```

or

```
document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("span")[3]
```

This last one ensures that there are not any hidden nodes that could mess it up.

Comment: Thanks, but there are a variable amount of child elements.

Comment: To me it seemed like the question was to always get the fourth span child, thus leading to my answer. I do of course agree that a function to get whatever type of element at whatever index within an other element would be better, but I did no interpret the question like that... reading the question again I see that I totally misunderstood though :-)

Comment: `TagName` that's it! So simple.

Comment: I use this technique frequently to get the first element eg document.getElementById("test").childNodes[0]

Comment: @LouiseEggleton there's `.firstChild` and `.firstChildElement` though

Answer (score 6):

Use the name of the id with the `getElementById`, no `#` sign before it. Then you can get the `span` child nodes using `getElementsByTagName`, and loop through them to find the one with the right class:

```
var doc = document.getElementById('test');

var c = doc.getElementsByTagName('span');

var e = null;
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    if (c[i].className == '4') {
        e = c[i];
        break;
    }
}

if (e != null) {
    alert(e.innerHTML);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/xB62U/

Comment: Sorry, that # was a typo. I can select the container div, but cannot select the child elements by tag name because that function is not working in ie8.

Comment: @spyderman4g63: The `getElementsByTagName` method works in IE 8. It is supported as far back as IE 5.5. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 5):

But be aware that old browsers doesn't support `getElementsByClassName`.

Then, you can do

```
function getElementsByClassName(c,el){
    if(typeof el=='string'){el=document.getElementById(el);}
    if(!el){el=document;}
    if(el.getElementsByClassName){return el.getElementsByClassName(c);}
    var arr=[],
        allEls=el.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for(var i=0;i<allEls.length;i++){
        if(allEls[i].className.split(' ').indexOf(c)>-1){arr.push(allEls[i])}
    }
    return arr;
}
getElementsByClassName('4','test')[0];
```

It seems it works, but be aware that an HTML class

- Must begin with a letter: A-Z or a-z
- Can be followed by letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"), and underscores ("_")

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, each time you can, you should use Array and its methods. They are much, much faster then looping over the whole DOM / wrapper, or pushing stuff into empty array. Majority of solutions presented here you can call Naive as described here (great article btw):

https://medium.com/@chuckdries/traversing-the-dom-with-filter-map-and-arrow-functions-1417d326d2bc

**My solution**: (live preview on Codepen: https://codepen.io/Nikolaus91/pen/wEGEYe)

```
const wrapper = document.getElementById('test') // take a wrapper by ID -> fastest
const itemsArray = Array.from(wrapper.children) // make Array from his children

const pickOne = itemsArray.map(item => { // loop over his children using .map() --> see MDN for more
   if(item.classList.contains('four')) // we place a test where we determine our choice
     item.classList.add('the-chosen-one') // your code here
})
```

Answer (score 3):

using querySelector

```js
var doc=document.getElementById("test");
console.log(doc.querySelector('.two').innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="test">
 <span class="one"></span>
 <span class="two">two</span>
 <span class="three"></span>
 <span class="four"></span>
</div>
```

Using querySelectorAll

```js
var doc=document.getElementById("test");
console.log(doc.querySelectorAll('*')[1].innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="test">
 <span class="one"></span>
 <span class="two">two</span>
 <span class="three"></span>
 <span class="four"></span>
</div>
```

using getElementsByTagNames

```js
var doc=document.getElementById("test");
console.log(doc.getElementsByTagName("SPAN")[1].innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="test">
 <span class="one"></span>
 <span class="two">two</span>
 <span class="three"></span>
 <span class="four"></span>
</div>
<span>ss</span>
```

Using getElementsByClassName

```js
var doc=document.getElementById("test");
console.log(doc.getElementsByClassName('two')[0].innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="test">
 <span class="one"></span>
 <span class="two">two</span>
 <span class="three"></span>
 <span class="four"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this would answer your question best

```
document.querySelector('* > span.four')
```

This will match the first child element (of any parent) it finds that is a span and also has a class "four" set to it

However since in your example you also had a parent element which you are able to retrieve by id, you could also use this instead

```
document.querySelector('#test > span.four')
```

If you have a parent element saved in a variable like in your example, and you wish to search the subtree of that element, using `:scope`, as Billizzard has mentioned already, is probably your best choice

```
doc.querySelector(':scope > span.four');
```

Little extra: If the child element you are looking for isn't a direct child descendent, but somewhere further down the subtree, you can actually just omit the `>` like so

```
document.querySelector('#test span.four')
```

Comment: On Stackoverflow this is an insufficient answer since you didn't explain anything.

Comment: Sorry I'll add a small description

Answer (score 3):

Another way

```
const result = [...(parentElement.children)].find(child => {
  return child.classList.contains('some-class-name');
});
```

First we spread the elements of the `NodeList` to turn it into an `Array` so we can make use of the `find()` method. Lastly, `find()` will return to us the first element whose `classList` property contains the given class name.

Answer (score 2):

The way i will do this using jquery is something like this..

> var targetedchild = $("#test").children().find("span.four");

Comment: question is about javascript not jQuery

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch the parent class by adding the line below. If you had an id, it would be easier with `getElementById`. Nonetheless,

```
var parentNode = document.getElementsByClassName("progress__container")[0];
```

Then you can use `querySelectorAll` on the parent `<div>` to fetch all matching `div`s with class `.progress__marker`

```
var progressNodes = progressContainer.querySelectorAll('.progress__marker');
```

`querySelectorAll` will fetch every `div` with the class of `progress__marker`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a relatively simple recursive solution.  I think a breadth-first search is appropriate here.  This will return the first element matching the class that is found.

```
function getDescendantWithClass(element, clName) {
    var children = element.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i].className &&
            children[i].className.split(' ').indexOf(clName) >= 0) {
            return children[i];
         }
     }
     for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
         var match = getDescendantWithClass(children[i], clName);
         if (match !== null) {
             return match;
         }
     }
     return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a few years old and there have been a few answers to this but I thought I would add my solution just in case it helps anyone. It's in the same vein as the answer given by **user2795540** and involves an array iterator.

If you're just wanting to get the first child that has the `four` class then you could use the `find` array iterator. Your browser will need to be able to support ES6 or you can use Babel to compile your JS into something all browsers will support. **IE will not support this without a polyfill**.

Using the same details you provided in your question it could look something like this:

```js
const parentNode = document.getElementById('test');
const childNode = Array.from(parentNode.childNodes).find(({ className }) => className === 'four');
```

The above solution will return the node you want to target and store it in the `childNode` variable.

You can find out more about the `find` array iterator at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: This a good answer. It will fail if the element has more than one class though. You can use `String.includes('yourclass')` to avoid this though. 
`const childNode = Array.from(parentNode.childNodes).find(({ className }) => className && className.includes('four'));`

Answer (score 0):

June 2018 update to ES6

```
    const doc = document.getElementById('test');
    let notes = null;
    for (const value of doc) {
        if (value.className === '4') {
            notes = value;
            break;
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

let notes = document.querySelector('#test .four')

Answer (score -2):

YUI2 has a [cross-browser implementation of `getElementsByClassName`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/dom/getelementsbyclassname.html).

Comment: Hmm. The example does work in IE8, but maybe it doesn't work in the case that you apply it to an object. In my case is set doc as a yui dom object and then use doc.getElementsByClassName. That's when it fails. edit: or maybe I don't understand how that object works and it is just a normal dom object?

Comment: @spyderman4g63 the YUI version of `getElementsByClassName` is a method of `YAHOO.util.Dom`. In your case, the call would look something like `YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName('four', 'span', 'test')`. You should probably read the docs to get a more detailed understanding of what that call is doing. The short version is that it will now look for `span` elements with the class `four` underneath the DOM element with `test` as its `id`.

Comment: @spyderman4g63 Yes, the result of the `get` call is just a DOM element. YUI doesn't take the sort of whole-sale 'wrap everything in a framework-specific object' approach that something like jQuery does, nor does it monkey-patch native objects like Prototype does (did? I haven't messed w/ Protoype in forever). In this respect, YUI is more like Dojo.

Answer (score -3):

Here is how I did it using the YUI selectors. Thanks to Hank Gay's suggestion.

```
notes = YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName('four','span','test');
```

where four = classname, span = the element type/tag name, and test = the parent id.

Answer (score -4):

Use `YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName()` from [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Dom.html#method_getElementsByClassName).