# HTML/Javascript scope

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been fiddling around with HTML lately and I have a question.

Is there a way to scope element's id as a child of another element?
It's difficult to describe, but here's an example.

```
<body>
  <div id="a">
    <div id="inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="b">
    <div id="inner"></div>
  </div> 
</body>
```

I do not know if this is legal (since "inner" is declared twice), but the problem is as follows:

Suppose I have a webpage full of square divs with their own styles and fixed positioning (kinda like Windows 8 metro),
I would like to be able to group all components of a particular square into that square, so that I can use javascript
to focus on the elements in the scope of say, in pseudocode.

```
ClickMeButtonDiv.ClickMeButton.value = parseInt(ClickMeButton.value) + 1;
```

In short, I want to know if it is possible to group all children of a div to that div, because if I have 100 squares on one page doing their own thing, it is a headache to keep all elements by id bound to global scope...

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: No, `id` must be unique per page.

Comment: I understand that, but I would like to know if there is any non-id way to deal with this problem, because if I have many different "scopes", and ids are bound to global scope, then the page effectively becomes unmanagable.

Comment: `id` is unique. use `class` instead.

Comment: Any reference to how to utilize class? As far as I read, you cannot getElementByClass, and I never heard of anybody "subclassing locally". I thought it was purely for CSS convenience.

Comment: Look into jQuery. It will make your life 100x easier. You can select an element by class very easily. For example, if you had a class `inner`, you could say `$(".inner")` to select all elements with that class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have non-unique IDs. You can use the `class` property though. Change `id="inner"` to `class="inner"` and if you're using JQuery, you could try using child selectors. For example:

```
$("#a > .inner");
```

Without jQuery

```
document.getElementById('a').getElementsByClassName('inner')[0];
```

Comment: is that using class or id?

Comment: It selects `id="a"` and then all `class="inner"`

Comment: I think this solves the problem, although I'm still really curious if this can be done in pure javascript.

Comment: If you want pure JS, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166753/how-to-get-child-element-by-class-name

Comment: Ah I see, so it iterates over elements and verifies classname, makes sense. This solves the problem, thanks! 4 minutes until I can accept answer.

Answer (score 2):

`id` must be unique. The grouping problem you describe is best solved using classes.

```
  <div id="a">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="b">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
```

If you want to read out values from `inner` elements I highly recommend to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) because it allows you to select elements by class.

```
<div id="a">
  <input type="text" class="inner" value="1" />
</div>
<div id="b">      
  <input type="text" class="inner" value="2" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#a input.inner').val(); // == 1
$('#b input.inner').val(); // == 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples, I was hoping it could be done without JQuery, but doing so appears to be messy, as I noted in a response earlier. Although it shouldn't matter since making something as sophisticated as I mentioned would make sense to take advantage of JQuery.

Comment: Well if it can be done with jQuery it is definitely possible in pure JS as well. But since the jQuery lib is so easy to use I'd use it. ;)

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that javascript does not allow direct way to access nested classes, which means you have to iterate over all the elements to find their class, then go into that element, then iterate over that element's elements and check their classes, which becomes even more compicated when it's deeper than two levels nested, possibly requiring loops or recursions. Ideally, I was hoping there would be a way to document.getElementByClass("a").getElementByClass("b"), or something like document.getObject("a.b") but oh well.