# How to get the classes of an element's children in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, children

i'm just creating a grid system for responsive web design and my code (simplified) looks like this:

```
<div id="row1">
<div class="type_3">
</div>
<div class="type_1">
</div>
<div class="type_2">
</div>
<div class="type_2">
</div>
</div>
```

Now I want to get the names of the classes and the order of the elements, that are direct children of .row1 as an array or string (or similar) in js.
The order is very important in this case.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance,
JBG

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get child element by class name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166753/how-to-get-child-element-by-class-name)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the children of `#row1` node:

```
var children = document.getElementById("row1").children;
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
    alert(children[i].className);
}
```

`alert` is just for a quick demo, do anything you want inside the loop. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/THwSV/).