# Convert getted result of InnerHTML text to an element

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have some code :

```
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id='myTdId'>
                    <input type='text' value='some value' />
                </td>
            </tr>

            ...

        </tbody>
    <table>
```

I want to get innerHTML of `myTdId` td element and get value of text input. Is it possible?

for example :

```
var tdInnerHTML = document.getElementById('myTdId').innerHTML;
// convert this to element operation and access to value of it ... 
console.log(tdInnerHTML.value); // :(
```

please help me, THANKS...

**EDIT :** 
I do not access to input text!

Comment: document.getElementById("myText").value, <input type='text' value='some value' id="myText" />

Comment: Checkif [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12166811/2968762) helps

Comment: The input value does not modify the HTML markup, so you can't get the value through the HTML.

Comment: `const a = document.querySelector('#myidid input'); console.log(a.value)`

Comment: @Abhi Thanks my friend

Comment: @wostex thanks, very good. this is better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using *childNodes* to navigate?

It is an array containing nodes of contained elements.

In your case...

```
var tdInputVal = document.getElementById('myTdId').childNodes[0].value;
console.log(tdInputVal ); // :(
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you add Id on the input itself?

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id='myTdId'>
                <input type='text' value='some value' id="myInput" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        ...

    </tbody>
<table>
```

Then access it via

```
var input = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
```

Or access it via tag

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative clear way is to have `id` or `class` on your HTML so you can get inner `value` easily.

For example

HTML:

`<input id="text-input" value="">`

Javascript

```
var inputValue = document.getElementById('text-input').value;
console.log(inputValue);
```

jQuery version

```
var inputValue = $('#text-input').val();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you need to call innerHTML on that element. You need to get child of the td element with id "myTdId". To do that you can use

```
var tdElement = document.getElementById('myTdId');
console.log(tdElement.children[0].value);
```

This should get you the value of the td Element without the need of setting id or class to the td element.

I am assuming you have only one element inside the td;

I did not test the code but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use getElementById than use on result object also getElementBy_XXX .
If you use getElementsByClassName or TagName you will get array of child element.

```js
//ELEMENT
var tdElement = document.getElementById('myTdId');

// INNER HTML
var tdInnerHTML = document.getElementById('myTdId').innerHTML;

var childElement = tdElement.getElementsByTagName("input");

//if td is only and always first element than we can use  : 
//childElement[0]

alert(childElement[0].value)
```

```html
<table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id='myTdId'>
                    <input type='text' value='some value' />
                </td>
            </tr>

       

        </tbody>
    <table>
    
    <script>
    
    //  I dont use this function but you can if you want
    function getElementInsideElement(baseElement, wantedElementID) {
    var elementToReturn;
    for (var i = 0; i < baseElement.childNodes.length; i++) {
        elementToReturn = baseElement.childNodes[i];
        if (elementToReturn.id == wantedElementID) {
            return elementToReturn;
        } else {
            return getElementInsideElement(elementToReturn, wantedElementID);
        }
    }
}
    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Use querySelector
var input = document.querySelector('#myTdId input');
var val = input.value;
```