# select elements by class that have a specific child element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a product list that is structured like the below HTML.

I am trying to select the elements with the `class="www-components-menu-product-list--item_DgfZL"`  that contain the elements with the class name `class="www-components-product-card--cbd_2luC9"`.

Then I want to hide those elements in a click function.

Please note. I have a lot of these items on the page, the function should apply to all the potential elements not just the two I have in the example.

I already understand how to do this with Jquery, but I am trying to avoid Jquery here.

This my attempt with javascript.

```
var itemClass = document.getElementsByClassName("www-components-menu-product-list--item_DgfZL");

for (i = 0; i < itemClass.length; i++) {

      var insideItemClass = itemClass.getElementsByClassName("www-components-product-card--hybrid_2AD7v");

        for (i = 0; i < insideItemClass.length; i++) {

            insideItemClass.style.display = "none";

        }

}
```

HTML Structure:

```
<div class="www-components-menu-product-list--item_DgfZL">

    <div class="www-components-product-card--card_2mjWk">


        <div>

            <div class="www-components-product-card--hybrid_2AD7v www-components-product-card--backdrop_Nq0th" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(62%);">

            </div>


            <div class="www-components-product-card--description_3un8n" style="height: 38%;">

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>


<div class="www-components-menu-product-list--item_DgfZL">

    <div class="www-components-product-card--card_2mjWk">


        <div>

            <div class="www-components-product-card--cbd_2luC9 www-components-product-card--backdrop_Nq0th" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(62%);">

            </div>


            <div class="www-components-product-card--description_3un8n" style="height: 38%;">

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>




<div class="www-components-menu-product-list--item_DgfZL">

    <div class="www-components-product-card--card_2mjWk">


        <div>

            <div class="www-components-product-card--cbd_2luC9 www-components-product-card--backdrop_Nq0th" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(62%);">

            </div>


            <div class="www-components-product-card--description_3un8n" style="height: 38%;">

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

MY ERROR

```
01:26:25.549 menubest.html:2923 Uncaught TypeError: itemClass.getElementsByClassName is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (menubest.html:2923)
```

Comment: The error is correct because `getElementsByClassName` returns an HTML collection so you can't call `getElementsByClassName` on `itemClass`.

Comment: use this: `insideItemClass[i].style.display = "none";` instead of `insideItemClass.style.display = "none";`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get child element by class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166753/how-to-get-child-element-by-class-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
itemClass[i].getElementsByClassName
insideItemClass[i].style.display = "none";
```

instead of

```
itemClass.getElementsByClassName
insideItemClass.style.display = "none";
```

Full code:

```
    var itemClass = document.getElementsByClassName("www-components-menu-product-list--item_DgfZL");

for (i = 0; i < itemClass.length; i++) {

      var insideItemClass = itemClass[i].getElementsByClassName("www-components-product-card--hybrid_2AD7v");

      if(insideItemClass.length > 0){
        itemClass.item(i).style.display = "none";
      }
}
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jeL0fezh/8/

Comment: this still only hides the inside element. not the entire item. here is a link

click yellow sativa button

[link](https://www.treaze.com/menubest.html)

Comment: Give me the link

Comment: I have updated code, did you try that? Still can't see the link.

Comment: [Click the Yellow sativa button please](https://www.treaze.com/menubest.html)     also all the code is in the source if that helps

Comment: Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jeL0fezh/2/ it's hiding the test33 properly.

Comment: @Aaron i have checked and above code is working. Can you please test?

Comment: im trying to hide the outer element but select that outer element based on it containing the inner element with the class www-components-product-card--hybrid_2AD7v

Comment: Outer elements means which one? Pease mention the class name.

Comment: i want to hide elements with this class name "www-components-menu-product-list--item_DgfZL",   when these elements contain elements with the  class"www-components-product-card--hybrid_2AD7v"

Comment: You have 3 classes: 1. www-components-menu-product-list--item_DgfZL 2.www-components-product-card--card_2mjWk and 3. www-components-product-card--hybrid_2AD7v   so which one you want to hide?

Comment: Hi, i have updated the code and the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jeL0fezh/8/. Now it will hide www-components-menu-product-list--item_DgfZL when these elements contain elements with the class"www-components-product-card--hybrid_2AD7v".

Comment: Please let me know if it works and don't forget to cast up vote and mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: it messes up my css a little bit, but i can figure that out. However this is what i'm looking for. Thank for your time and effort.