# <Script> functions not working when reducing screen size

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a problem with the reservation module I developed in the last few months. You can have a look at it at the following address:

[Taxi milan](http://www.ros-black-taxi.com/)

Everything is working perfectly except for one issue. When I reduce the size of the browser window, I decided to make the image disappear and leave only the reservation module. When it is resized it stops working: all the script functions (the one providing the arrivals based on the departure selection and the "get price" button) do not work. Can you tell me what is causing the issue?

Below you can find the main parts of the code in which you may find the issue.

**HOMEPAGE**

```html
<body>
<?php
    $explode = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if($explode[1] == 'it' and $explode[2] == 'ros-ncc'){
?>
<div id="image">
    <div id="modulemax">
    <?php
    require('wp-content/themes/customizr/prenota/index.php');
?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
   }else if($explode[1] == '' and $explode[2] == ''){
?>
<div id="image">
    <div id="modulemax">
<?php    
require('wp-content/themes/customizr/book/index.php');
?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php    
} else {
    }
    ?>
<div id="modulemin">
    <?php
    $explode = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if($explode[1] == 'it' and $explode[2] == 'ros-ncc'){
         require('wp-content/themes/customizr/prenota/index.php');
    }else if($explode[1] == '' and $explode[2] == ''){
        require('wp-content/themes/customizr/book/index.php');
    } else {
}
?>
</div>
</body>
```

INDEX - BOOK (english reservation module)

```html
<?php include "prova1.php"; ?>
<script>
function getArrival(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "wp-content/themes/customizr/book/process.php",
    data:'dep_name='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#arrivals-list").html(data);
    }
    });
}
</script>
<script>
function chk(){
    var var1=document.getElementById('departures-list').value;
    var var2=document.getElementById('arrivals-list').value;
    var var3=document.getElementById('passengers').value;
    var var4=document.getElementById('bags').value;
    var dataString='var1='+ var1 +'&var2='+ var2 +'&var3='+ var3 +'&var4='+ var4;
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "wp-content/themes/customizr/book/process2.php",
    data:dataString,
    cache:false,
    success: function(html){
        $('#resbox').html(html);
    }
    });
    return false;
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="rcorners1">
    <form action='wp-content/themes/customizr/book/index.php' method='post'>
    <label>Departure:</label>
        <select name="departures" id="departures-list" class="form-control" onchange="getArrival(this.value);">
        <option value="">Select Departure</option>
                    <?php
                        require('wp-content/themes/customizr/book/prova1.php');
                        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM departures";  
                        $result1 = $mysqli->query($sql1);
                        while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()){
                    ?>   
                    <option value="<?php echo $row1["dep_name"]; ?>|<?php echo $row1["dep_air"]; ?>"><?php echo $row1["dep_name"]; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <label>Arrival:</label>
        <select id="arrivals-list" name="arrivals">
        <option value="">Select Arrival</option>
        </select>
<input id="input" type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return chk()" value="Get Price" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and look at the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to improve your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different `div` in your website. One of it has `id = image`, and second is `id = modulemin`. Div with `id = image` hiding when `screen size < 800px width` with css( `display = none` ), and second is hiding when `screen size > 799px width` with css( `display = none` ). And both of them have similar forms. Why you need it? Why to have 2 similar forms only for different screen sizes?

Your main problem is with `id's` of your `form inputs` variables `var1, var2 ...`.
Your trying to got some info using `ids` of `inputs` in this lines:

```
var var1=document.getElementById('departures-list').value;
```

But, as you can understand, you always will get only `inputs` from first form in `DOM tree`, because after finding first occurrence of any `id`, `js` stoped searching and return it. More detailed about it you can find in any `js` documentation.

You can use `class` instead of `id` for getting all `inputs` with same classname from page. You can use some differ `id` for forms, and then get `inputs` with `id/name/class/tagname` as child `node` of that form( [ex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12166811/8053001) ).

Also, strongly not recommend to send `ajax` request to some other file. Instead of it, use [wp-ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side).

Comment: Thank you for your reply but everything already works fine. The only problem I have it is only with the reduced module. When the screen size is larger than 799px it works properly. I created two div because when the screen is thinner i want the image to disappear and the module to expand.

Comment: Thank you very much. I left just one module using CSS and everything works fine now. Have a great day.