# Win8 JS App: How can one prevent backward navigation? Can't set WinJS.Navigation.canGoBack

Tags: windows-8, navigation, winjs, appbar

Fairly new to developing for Windows 8, I'm working on an app that has a rather flat model. I have looked and looked, but can't seem to find a clear answer on how to set a WinJS page to prevent backward navigation. I have tried digging into the API, but it doesn't say anything on the matter.

The code I'm attempting to use is

```
WinJS.Navigation.canGoBack = false;
```

No luck, it keeps complaining about the property being read only, however, there are no setter methods to change it.

Thanks ahead of time,
~Sean

Comment: I think the way I would handle this is to hide the back button on pages that you want to disable backward navigation.

Comment: @bmceldowney See my answer post for comment. I am going to let the question stand for a few days in case you can provide a better solution for me. Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`canGoBack` does only have a getter (defined in `base.js`), and it reflects the absence or presence of the backstack; namely `nav.history.backstack`.

The appearance of the button itself is controlled by the disabled attribute on the associated button DOM object, which in turn is part of a CSS selector controlling visibility. So if you do tinker with the display of the Back button yourself be aware that the navigation plumbing is doing the same.

Setting the backstack explicitly is possible; there's a sample the [Navigation and Navigation History Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Navigation-sample-cf242faa)  that includes restoring a history as well as preventing navigation using [beforenavigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229838.aspx), with the following code:

```
    // in ready
    WinJS.Navigation.addEventListener("beforenavigate", this.beforenavigate);


    //
    beforenavigate: function (eventObject) {
        // This function gives you a chance to veto navigation. This demonstrates that capability
        if (this.shouldPreventNavigation) {
            WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Navigation to " + eventObject.detail.location + " was prevented", "sample", "status");
            eventObject.preventDefault();
        }
    },
```

Comment: The funny thing about this answer is that I have both of those links bookmarked in a folder dedicated to this project. Is there a way to utilize the beforenavigate() function to disable the backstack in a roundabout manner?

Comment: Not sure why this isn't the correct answer overall. Good show mate.

Comment: Updated to the accepted answer. Looking back over the problem after some additional years of experience...xD As Julius Caesar said, "Experience is the teacher of all things."

Answer (score 3):

You can't change canGoBack, but you can disable the button to hide it and free the history stack.

```
    // disabling and hiding backbutton
    document.querySelector(".win-backbutton").disabled = true;
    // freeing navigation stack
    WinJS.Navigation.history.backStack = [];
```

This will prevent going backward and still allow going forward.

Comment: So how about keyboard navigation, e.g. Alt+Cursor Left?

Comment: @0xA3 haven't tried. As backStack is empty, I would say nothing happens. But I might be wrong. If you get an Exception with keyboard, report-it to me and I'll look for a solution this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

So lots of searching and attempting different methods of disabling the Back Button, finally found a decent solution. It has been adapted from another stackoverflow question.

*Original algorithm: [How to Get Element By Class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript)*

---

**MY SOLUTION**

At the beginning of a fragment page, right as the page definition starts declaring the ready: function, I used an adapted version of the above algorithm and used the resulting element selection to set the disabled attribute.

```
        // Retrieve Generated Back Button
        var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i;

        for (i in elems)
        {
            if((" "+elems[i].className+" ").indexOf("win-backbutton") > -1)
            {
                var d = elems[i];
            }
        }

        // Disable the back button
        d.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

The code gets all elements from the page's DOM and filters it for the generated back button. When the proper element is found, it is assigned to a variable and from there we can set the disabled property.

---

I couldn't find a lot of documentation on working around the default navigation in a WinJS Navigation app, so here are some methods that failed (for reference purposes):

- Getting the element by class and setting | May have failed from doing it wrong, as I have little experience with HTML and javascript.
- Using the above method, but setting the attribute within the for loop breaks the app and causes it to freeze for unknown reasons.
- Setting the attribute in the default.js before the navigation is finished. | The javascript calls would fail to recognize either methods called or DOM elements, presumably due to initialization state of the page.

There were a few others, but I think there must be a better way to go about retrieving the element after a page loads. If anyone can enlighten me, I would be most grateful.
~Sean R.

Comment: @bmceldowney If you have a better way, please share it. As there is no private messaging within StackOverflow, post an answer. Thanks!