# How to handle all links in a class?

Tags: javascript, dom

I know how to handle a link with an id:

```
var a = document.getElementById("mylink");
a.onclick = function() {
  alert("ok");
};
```

But if I have 3 links within one class *.lotsOfLinks* and I want
to handle each one just like I did with Id.

What's the best and short way?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you try jQuery or other javascript libraries?  (if it is possible on your project). If it is possible, you may check this: http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use jQuery for such a easy actions.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// use querySelectorAll for greater browser compatibility
var a = document.querySelectorAll(".mylink");

// make your handler
var handler = function() {
  alert("ok");
};

// iterate the collection, and assign the handler
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].onclick = handler;
}
```

Note that `querySelectorAll` doesn't work in IE6/7, but I would imagine you're not supporting those JavaScript environments at this point.

Answer (score 4):

Do it like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("lotsOfLinks");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function() {
        alert("ok");
    };
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` is not supported in older versions of IE

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    if (a[i].className == "lotsOfLinks"){
        a[i].onclick = function(){ alert("ok"); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use a `for-in` loop like that. It causes problems on array-like structures, especially DOM collections. Your original loop was better, though for that type of collection, the `.length` should be cached.

Comment: i use `for-in` usually on those kind of arrays only when i'm querying against an attribute, i realize that this kind of arrays has one extra item at the end (i'm not sure what is it for though) and it would cause problems when the loop reachs the end of the array if i'm querying against elements, but i think it should be fine in this example?

Comment: It won't hurt here, but if there comes a time where the indexed order is important, there could be issues. The extra property it's hitting is the `.length`. Sometimes there are methods as well. Overall, the `for-in` should be avoided for ordered lists. It causes too many potential problems, and gives no real benefit. Even though there's no issue here, other will people see it and therefore use it, unaware of the potential problems.

Comment: I agree that other people might misuse it so changed it back to normal `for` loop. thanks for explaining the `.length` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');` but it's not supported in IE versions prior to 9 without a polyfill

http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname

Answer (score 0):

```
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("lotsOfLinks");
  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     elements[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
         alert("ok");
     }
  }
```

used the addEventListener() function.