# Pass data from div tags to javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, button

**HTML**

```
<li id="a1">
    <div><p>Some Text1!</p></div>
    <div><a href="#"></a>Some Text2!</div>  
    <div><input id="a1b" type="button" onClick="fun()"/></div>      
</li>
```

How can I get `Some Text1!` and `Some Text2!` ,i.e, some text from first and second `div` and pass it to function `fun()` in third `div`?

Comment: I was thinking about assigning id to all the tags but looking for better solution than that.

Comment: Then please explain what would make a solution "better" and why ids would be troublesome in this case.

Comment: How was this off-topic ?

Comment: Try reading the banner below. It explains exactly why.

Comment: Why do you have to be rude ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign an Id to them and use `document.getElementById` to access

```
<li id="a1">
    <div><p id="text1">Some Text1!</p></div>
    <div id="text2"><a href="#"></a>Some Text2!</div>  
    <div><input id="a1b" type="button" onClick="fun(document.getElementById('text1').innerText,document.getElementById('text2').innerText)"/></div>      
</li>
```

Your `fun` function:

```
function fun(text1,text2){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the divs with `Some Text1!` and `Some Text2!` an `id` or a `class`. That way you can do the following:

**Via IDs:**

```
<li id="a1">
    <div id="text1"><p>Some Text1!</p></div>
    <div id="text2"><a href="#"></a>Some Text2!</div>  
    <div><input id="a1b" type="button" onClick="fun()"/></div>
</li>

<script>
function fun()
{
      var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");
      var text2 = document.getElementById("text2");

      //do stuff with text1 and text2. E.g.: alert them:
      alert(text1.innerHTML);
      alert(text1.innerHTML);
}
```

**And for doing it via classes:**

```
<li id="a1">
    <div class="identify"><p>Some Text1!</p></div>
    <div class="identify"><a href="#"></a>Some Text2!</div>  
    <div><input id="a1b" type="button" onClick="fun2('identify')"/></div>      
</li>

function fun2(matchClass)
{
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i;
    for (i in elems) {
        if((' ' + elems[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + matchClass + ' ')
            > -1) 
    {
        //do stuff with the elements. E.g.: Alert them:
        alert(elems[i].innerHTML);
    }
}
</script>
```

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3808886/866930

Answer (score 1):

```
var divEle[] = document.getElementById("a1").childNodes;

for(var i=0; i<divEle.length;i++)
{
    console.log(divEle[i].firstChild.innerHTML);
}
```

This will print inner text within div elements.

You can define function like:

```
divELe[2].setAttribute("onclick", "function("+divEle[0].firstChild.innerHTML+","+divEle[1].firstChild.innerHTML+")");
```