# Add div below particular div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have some class name fawas that displays some content. Actually i have to add some content below the Div in java script.please help me.

```
<div class="fawas">
    this is my name fawas khan.
</div>
```

my javascript code is

> var dynamic = "this is my contact number.";
>   var _body = document.getElementsByTagName('body') [0].innerHTML
>   =dynamic;

what i'm getting is only a appended div.

Answer (score 2):

In pure javaScript, getting an element by className is ugly.  See [How to Get Element By Class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript) for more information.

Basically, you'll want this function:

```
function getElementsByClass(tagType, className) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName(tagType);
    var returns = [];
    for (var i in elems) {
        if ((' ' + elems[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') > -1) {
            returns.push(elems[i]);
        }
    }
    return returns;
}
```

Once you have that, the rest is not too bad:

```
var dynamic = document.createElement("div");
dynamic.innerHTML = "this is my contact number.";

var elements = getElementsByClass("div", "fawas");
if (elements.length > 0) {
    // just change the first, as you did in your post
    elements[0].parentNode.insertBefore(dynamic, elements[0].nextSibling);
}
```

I dynamically create your new div, rather than just a text string.

Then, I get the parent of the element you want to insert after, use the `insertBefore` function on whatever is after the element of your choice.

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27wmP/).

As others have shown you, this can be a lot cleaner using jQuery.  I don't know enough `node.js` to know if it has functions that will be more convenient, so I gave a pure JS solution.

Comment: Great answer, in pure JS and then a note about jQuery being an option.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're interested in jQuery solution, here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/xbFf9/)

```
<div class="fawas">
  this is my name fawas khan.
</div>


$(function(){
  var dynamic = ('this is my contact number.');
  $('.fawas').after('<div class="fawas2">'+dynamic+'</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html should be,

```
<div class="fawas">
    this is my name fawas khan.
</div>
<div id="fawas-2">
</div>
```

Your script should be,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var dynamic = "this is my contact number."; 
document.getElementById('fawas-2').innerHTML =dynamic;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

var oldcontent = document.getElementsByTagName('body') [0].innerHTML;

document.getElementsByTagName('body') [0].innerHTML = oldcontent + dynamic

Where dynamic is the content you want to add