# How do you switch an element's background color when a child element is hovered?

Tags: css

I was wondering, how do you (or can you) change the background color of a element using purely css coding. I mean, when you have css like this:

```
body{
    background-color:grey;
}
.button{
    color:blue;
}
```

And then you have :

```
.button:hover{
    color:yellow;
}
```

My question is, can you make the body background color change when you hover over the element with the class `.button`?

Comment: In this instance, no, because there are no parent selectors present in CSS. You would need JS to transverse the DOM like this.

Comment: Basically..you can't. CSS will not allow you to affect elements higher up the DOM than themselves. JS/JQ answer is required.

Comment: In the future ([CSS Selectors Level 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-selectors4-20130502/)) you might be able to do this with CSS, e.g. `body! .button:hover` to select parents (or "determine selector subjects" to be a bit more precise), but the spec's still a draft and browser support isn't really here yet. Until then it'll be JS for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS does not handle relations/interactions between an element and its parent. This might require Javascript. Here's a jQuery example :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").hover(function(){
        $("body").css("background-color", "newcolor");
    }
}
```

Another try without jQuery :

```
function onButtonHover(){
    document.body.style.background = color;
}
```

You would need to bind this function to the `onMouseHover` event on every `.button` element though (or see [JoshC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2680216/joshc)'s fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5a9TS/) :

```
<button class="button" onMouseOver="onButtonHover()">MyButton</button>
```

More about this event : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onmouseover.asp. Note that the opposite interaction could be done is CSS though (parent-to-child relation) :

```
body:hover .button{
    background-color: newColor;
}
```

Comment: 1+ For the option without jQuery.. you could also add something like this if you wanted unobtrusive JavaScript http://jsfiddle.net/5a9TS/

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I didn't think it could be done, i was just checking.

Comment: How would i change the background color of another element such as <input> or <div>?

Comment: Replace `$("body")` by `$("div#id")` or `$("div.class")`, if you use jQuery. Otherwise, `document.body` must become `document.getElementById("divId")`. Selecting by class without JQ is a little trickier. See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript - @JoshC +1 for your fiddle, much nicer.

Comment: I was using document.getElementById but i accidentally capitalized the "G" in "get" so it didn't work. Thank you for all your help!