# How to replace class name for element without ID?

Tags: javascript

Pure JS please:
Hi,
This thread: [How to Get Element By Class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript)
contains the starting point for my question.
How can I replace the class name itself?
I just can't seem to get it to work using examples in the link above. 
Here's my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2qyt4sg9/):

Thanks a lot!

```
<div class="ggg">blavlavbla </div>

function replaceClass()
{
   var plusLinks = document.querySelectorAll('ggg');
   var firstLink = plusLinks[0];
   firstLink.setAttribute('class', 'aw-top-content-mod');
}

replaceClass();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change an element's CSS class with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

Comment: @ElYobo It's not really a duplicate of that. His problem isn't really with changing the class, it's with the selector to find the elements in the first place.

Comment: nopt a duplicate since I refer to an element WITHOUT ID.

Comment: I suggest rewriting your question; the class changing part is a duplicate, your question is then "how do I get an element without an ID".

Answer (score 1):

Just add `.` to the class name:

```
   function replaceClass()
             {
                 var plusLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.ggg');
                 var firstLink = plusLinks[0];
                 firstLink.setAttribute('class', 'aw-top-content-mod');
             }
     replaceClass();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onvbL142/)

Comment: @AdiSolar sure! btw always check your console/browser developer tools when things go wrong. In this case you would see `firstLink` is `undefined` when using `ggg` and not `.ggg`

Comment: I have a widget that is started via a link to a script in the cloud. This script creates div elements etc. on the page. And that comes with css properties defined with "!important". So essentially, I'm trying to override the class that's being created on the fly. Problem is, I don't seem to "catch" it on the page because it takes the widget script time to "draw" the elements and by that time my own script has already finished and of course it doesn't find the element. Is there a way to tell my script to run when the other is finished besides placing it below the widget script call?

Comment: Yes, you could call your function only after page finishes loading by listening to the `document.ready` event or you could simply use `setTimeout` and run your code in delay.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) instead of [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) which has more browser support. You can do it like.

```js
function replaceClass()
{
    var firstLink = document.getElementsByClassName('ggg')[0];
    firstLink.setAttribute('class', 'aw-top-content-mod');
}
        
 replaceClass();
```

```css
.aw-top-content-mod
{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="ggg">blavlavbla </div>
```