# Multiple card flip using getElelementsByClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing a card flip using CSS3 and javascript on multiple divs. I'm using desssandro's 3d Card Flip but his is only using an ID and therefore one div at a time. I have several cards in one page that I want to flip. How can I do it?

Here's the desandro's script and a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/vanduzled/nawdpj5j/

```
var init = function() {
  var card = document.getElementById('card');

  document.getElementById('flip').addEventListener( 'click', function(){
    card.toggleClassName('flipped');
  }, false);
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

If I make my divs a class instead of id's, the script below doesn't work:

```
var init = function() {
  var card = document.getElementById('card');

  document.getElementById('flip').addEventListener( 'click', function(){
    card.toggleClassName('flipped');
  }, false);
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

*EDIT*

I created a fiddle byclassname but it doesn't work

http://jsfiddle.net/vanduzled/omLac95t/

Comment: Try getElementsByClassName(), not getelementByClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/nawdpj5j/6/ I'll leave the styling to you. `getElementsByClassName` returns an array so you need to go through the elemnts in the array and call `toggleClassName` on each. I also modified the css to replace `#card` with `.card`

```
var init = function() {
  var cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");  
  document.getElementById('flip').addEventListener( 'click', function(){
      for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
         cards[i].toggleClassName('flipped');
      }
  }, false);
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

**Update:**

See http://jsfiddle.net/nawdpj5j/10/

add data-targetid to flip buttons:

```
<button class="flip" data-targetid="card">Flip Card</button>
```

Get all flip items and find the button to flip from button's dataset:

```
var init = function() {
  var flippers = document.getElementsByClassName("flip");

    for(i = 0; i < flippers.length; i++){
        flippers[i].addEventListener( 'click', function(){
            var cardID = this.dataset.targetid;
            var card = document.getElementById(cardID);
            card.toggleClassName('flipped');
  }, false);
    }
};
```

Comment: This might work. But can the cards have separate its own button? like for example #flip1, #flip2

Comment: You can have multiple buttons but then you don't need to flip them by class name, just give them different ids. I thought you wanted to flip all cards on page with a single click and that's why you wanted to flip by class name?

Comment: This is what I actually need. The code is very literal though. I thought there were other options. I need to do 8 cards so I just repeat this 8 times right?

Comment: @user3655840 OK to use jQuery, yeah?

Comment: @user3655840 See the update to the answer. It's using javascript and you need to write the code once, but you need to add `data-targetid` to the flip buttons to indicate the id of the div to flip.

Comment: will you able to help wit this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/26965050/3655840 @artm

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues:

1. The `click` event is being added to the button, so it should be `getElementsById('flip')`.
2. Retrieving the card should be `getElementsByClassName` or you can use jQuery's `$('.card')`.
3. The html and css are written for a single card.

---

```
var init = function() {
    var cards = $('.card');

    document.getElementById('flip').addEventListener( 'click', function(){
        $.each(cards, function( key, value ) {      
            value.toggleClassName('flipped');
        });
    }, false);
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

Here is a solution that works for multiple cards: http://jsfiddle.net/pwee167/nawdpj5j/7/

Comment: The above example uses jQuery to find the cards with `$('.card'), but it should work equally well with `getElementsByClassName`. This jsFiddle demonstrates that: http://jsfiddle.net/pwee167/nawdpj5j/8/

Comment: What browser/version are you using to test your code in?

Comment: Now it works. I'm using several browsers mainly IE, FF, GC. But I need it work with individual button per card. Not one button for several cards.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the top solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript).

The answer basically assigns the return value of `getElementByClassName()` to an array an then traverses it. When applied to you problem, it might look like this:

Also, [Working JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9u3tu4mj/7/).

```
var init = function() {
  var cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');

  document.getElementById('flip').addEventListener( 'click', function(){
    for (var x=0; x<cards.length; x++) {  
      cards[x].toggleClassName('flipped');
    }
  }, false);
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

Comment: I tried your code but the card doesn't flip. I tried it with one div but here's an fiddle of two divs

http://jsfiddle.net/vanduzled/9u3tu4mj/

Comment: On your fiddle, when you click on the first button, the two cards flip. I need button for one card. The second button doesn't do anything.

Comment: Oh so you want each button to flip a separate card? I thought you waned one button to flip multiple cards? Anyway, glad you got it resolved.