# What's the equivalent of dataset.targetid in IE10?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm making a card flip in 3d with multiple divs. It's working fine on modern browsers except IE10. I'm having an error:

> Unable to get property 'targetid' of undefined or null reference

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vanduzled/f4sk1u7q/

```
var init = function() {
  var flippers = document.getElementsByClassName("flip");

    for(i = 0; i < flippers.length; i++){
        flippers[i].addEventListener( 'click', function(){
            var cardID = this.dataset.targetid;
            var card = document.getElementById(cardID);
            card.toggleClassName('flipped');
  }, false);
    }


};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

Comment: IE < 11 doesn't support `dataset` as it turns out, use `this.getAttribute('data-targetid');`