# how to disable getelement() using row index javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a grid with values

I need to disable the textbox with ID as minutes for 2nd row. Following sample does not work.

```
document.getElementById("h_ID")[2].readOnly = true;
```

Can someone help me with the syntax?

Comment: **document.getElementById** doesn't return an array, so, you can't select the 2nd item.

try to select by ClassName

Comment: more importantly , `id` cannot & should not be re-used.

Comment: I have to use Ie7.. getElementsByClassName wont work . Any alternate?

Comment: IE 7 is extinct like the dinosaurs. Do not support them .

Comment: cant help it. Client requirement

Answer (score 1):

[Only one element can have a given id in a HTML document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

That's why `document.getElementById("minutes")` doesn't return a collection but a unique element. Don't use id in your case but classes.

So your code will be

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("minutes")[2].readOnly = true;
```

Comment: As explained in my answer, your HTML is invalid. Use classes instead of id.

Comment: I have to use IE7, getElementsByClassName wont work there

Comment: If you really need to use IE7, you should use a helper library to query elements, for example jQuery or sizzle. You'll find alternate solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript) if you don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById` returns only one element, because you are not supposed to have more than one element with an id on the page. Switch all the `id="minutes"` to `class="minutes"` and then use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('minutes')[2].readOnly = true;
```

Comment: am using struts2, if i add class instead of id it shows yellow warning sign       <s:textfield name="minutesStr" value = "%{minutesStr}" onblur="minsValidator('%{empNum}',this);" class="minutes"  theme="simple" cssClass="txtbox_mandatory"/>

Comment: You should add the class to the cssClass attribute like that:
<s:textfield name="minutesStr" value = "%{minutesStr}" onblur="minsValidator('%{empNum}',this);" theme="simple" cssClass="txtbox_mandatory minutes"/>

Comment: I have to use Ie7.. getElementsByClassName wont work here

Comment: You can add that functionality by the following code:
document.getElementsByClassName = document.getElementsByClassName || function(cl) {
  var retnode = [];
  var elem = this.getElementsByTagName('*');
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    if((' ' + elem[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cl + ' ') > -1) retnode.push(elem[i]);
  }
  return retnode;
};