# If statement from span "1 left"?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I need to create an if statement in Js fetching when there's only **1 left** (product) in stock. How would I go about this?

HTML on productpage:

```
<div id="product-spec">
 <div class="row">
  <ul class="col-xs-12">
   <li class="h4">
    <span class="availabilty"
     <span class="small">1 left</span>
    </span>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

My Javascript so far:

```
if (.small == 1 left) { 
// execute this code 
}
```

[W3 Schools - If Statements](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) doesn't make me more sane.

Comment: Don's use W3Schools for reference, ever. Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript) to figure how to select an element by class in javascript. Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to learn about `innerHTML` in javascript and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) to get your head around value comparison in javascript. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
if(document.querySelectorAll(".small")[0].innerHTML==="1 left"){
// get funky
}
```

**[EDIT]**

```
if($(".small").eq(0).text() == "1 left"){ 
$(".small").eq(0).prepend( "<div style="lots of styling"></div>" ); 
 }
```

Comment: Maybe something like this? if($(element).text() == "1 left")

Comment: that would be the superfluous jQuery way of doing it, yes: `if($(".small").eq(0).text() == "1 left"){ // monkey business }`

Comment: I want to call the if statement, and then .prepend style with jquery. What is the proper way of doing so? $( "if statement" ).prepend( "<div style="lots of styling"></div>" );

Comment: if($(".small").eq(0).text() == "1 left").prepend("<div style="lots of styling"></div>"); **?**

Comment: see my revised answer. I would suggest you spend a little time learning vanilla js before you start using frameworks like jQuery - you seem to be lacking fundamentals. And btw, this: `<span class="availabilty"` isn't going to help you much, either. s/b: `<span class="availabilty">`

Comment: Thank you Lucas! I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You write like this

```
var product = document.getElementsByClassName('modal_link')[0];
// if inner text exist
if(product.innerText) {
    // getting count products from string
    var countProduct = parseInt(product.innerText, 10);
    if(countProduct === 1) {
        console.log('Left');
    }
}
```