# How to get class name through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I get the class name through JavaScript using element name from classic HTML.

Like:

```
<input name="xxx" class="CheckBox" onchange="CheckOnChange()"
       type="CHECKBOX" checked="" value="Y">
```

I want to check the fields which has the class name "Checkbox" .

How can I solve this? Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript

Comment: What class name are you trying to import? Post your code and explain a bit more so that we could help better.

Comment: I would use jQuery('.classname') for that purpose.

Comment: *"How do I get the class name...using element name...? I want to check the fields which has the class name "Checkbox"."* - These two requirements seem to contradict each other. Also, if you are trying to do this with JS, why the C# and vb.net tags?

Comment: @nnnn i am using vb.net the call the JS

Comment: The question wording is unclear. Is your question: "How do I test if an element has a particular class?", or "How do I test if an element with the 'Checkbox' class is checked?", or "How do I set all checkboxes with the 'Checkbox' class to be checked?" Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reversed my question to get the required output. Here by reading the class name,I am getting the element name using the below JS:

```
     var elementName = "";
        var dd = document.getElementsByClassName("CheckBox");
        for (i = 0; i <= dd.length - 1; i++) {
            if (elementName == "")
            { elementName = dd[i].name; }
            else
            {
                elementName = elementName + "," + dd[i].name;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of solutions. First to access element classname you use this code :

```
element.className
```

Next if you want to test if a classname exist inside the element list, you can test it with indexOf but you could have false positive. class `"foo"` is not present in the following element.className : `"foobar foobuzz"`

Best way is to use RegExp :

```
checkIfElementHasClassName(element, className) {
   return (new RegExp('^|\\s' + className + '\\s|$')).test(element.className);
}
```