# Getting the actual name of the class, and not the element within it?

Tags: javascript, html, class, parameters, getelementsbyclassname

To get elements using a class name, `document.getElementsByClassName()` can be used.

But is there a function in JavaScript to get the actual name of the class itself?

Example:

```js
var classElement = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
       var printResult = document.getElementById('result');
    
       printResult.innerHTML = classElement[0].innerHTML;
```

```html
<div class="myClass">Hello</div>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

printResult will just print out "Hello".  What if I want the result to print out the string **"myClass"** which is the actual class name?

I tried `classElement[0].className.innerHTML` but it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get class name through JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39114858/how-to-get-class-name-through-javascript)

Comment: Uh, if you selected the element by that name you already know the name?!

Answer (score 2):

`className` is a property of the dom node containing the classes of the element.
You don't need to add `innerHTML`, which is another property of the dom node and returns/sets the html content of the corresponding element.

```js
var classElement = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
var printResult = document.getElementById('result');

printResult.innerHTML = classElement[0].className;
```

```html
<div class="myClass">Hello</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```