# Change text from Facebook Share button only in specific div

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, class, facebook-graph-api

How can I change the text from a Facebook share button "shareOnfacebook" with "shareOnFB" only from this div class="result-share-buttons-container" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Get Element By Class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript)

Comment: You should use getElementsByClassName() method

Comment: getElementsByClassName() will fix the issue