# How to Identify button with ClassName and onlick event in JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, scripting, automated-tests, html

I want create a script for auto click button on planned time. 
Example: I want click a button in hour X in a web page (reload every hour).
THe problem is about identify that button with ClassName and onClick, onClick function's identify button.

How can I do?

HTML CODE:
`<button class="reward_link_redeem_button_style " onclick="RedeemRPProduct('free_points_100')">REDEEM</button>`

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Get Element By Class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript)

Comment: I want identify button with ClassName AND onclick event

Answer (score 0):

Change the callback to pass `this` as well

```
<button class="reward_link_redeem_button_style" onclick="RedeemRPProduct(this, 'free_points_100')">click</button>
```

in the callback, the first argument (`this`, will be the button element)

```
function RedeemRPProduct (element, whatever) {
  element.className == "reward_link_redeem_button_style"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, so do I modify html web page or must I add this in a script? 
Another question, How I can automated click in a fixed time of redeem button?