# How do I get an array of divs with a specific class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

So I've been working on this web-project that demands a gallery with a slider underneath it. I've used this JavaScript so far to solve the problem in a forEach(element) function:

```
var divnumber = Array.from(element.parentNode.children).indexOf(element);
```

So the pagination changes by the index of the clicked element.

But since I need to make it responsive and the graphic designer demands something different in the mobile view I would need to get the number of the divs by using their class. Basically - the same array but different values.

Is there any way to tweak that line of code a bit to let it get the index of the element by its class instead of their parent? Here's the pen for more: https://codepen.io/ridonibishi/pen/BaNyBva

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How to get all elements with a specified class is a case for a search provider (Google, Yahoo, Bing, ...) but not SO

Comment: I saw this question an our ago. None of the comments were helpful?

Comment: Or the SO search -> [How to Get Element By Class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript)

Comment: Funny enough none of the comments were helpful - and I think I just have to state that I'm still new to JavaScript every single time I ask something... unless I want ironic comments about how easy it is to fix it while not being helpful at all

Comment: Because this is not how SO works (at least not in the past...) -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/261593) - tl;dr: a lot

Comment: @AkinOkegbile You've seen the (at the moment) only answer?

Comment: Accept your answer as well @OP.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry for the inconvenience! I try my best to use SO as my last option - which was the case this time since I don't understand JavaScript to its core as much as I would like to. I did not know that Array.from() could be used in the way as I intended to use it until I found out that I just could add getElementsbyClassName() since I did not find anything similar. Hopefully, it will work out better next time. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
  var divnumber = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('class')).indexOf(element);
```

It works as intended.